# How did I gain this 3 rep?

Tags: support, reputation

I just gained 3 rep out of no where from a question that has gotten zero votes:

http://fwei.tk/shot2.png

http://fwei.tk/shot1.png

Why/how did I get this rep? Is it a bug?

Comment: 1 upvote and 1 downvote.

Comment: Ah well... duh!

Comment: Upvotes on questions are worth +5 only.

Comment: Ok, and now I can't edit my old comment

Answer (score 10):

You got an upvote for +5 and a downvote for -2. We can prove this as follows:

Let x be the number of downvotes and y be the number of upvotes. Then we have

```
(1) -x  + y = 0
(2) -2x + 5y = 3
```

(1) follows from the total vote count being zero, and (2) follows from the net rep change.

Multiplying the first equation by -5 and adding to the second equation gives

```
3x = 3
```

Hence `x = 1`, and substituting into the first equation yields `y = 1` as well. Conversely, substituting `x = y = 1` solves the two equations, and therefore it is the one and only solution.

One can verify in general that if `V` is the net vote count and `R` is the net rep change then

```
x = (R - 5V) / 3
y = (85 - R) / 3
```

For what it's worth, 1000 rep users can see this by clicking the vote count, and there's a user script that lets < 1000 rep users see as well. However, this is clearly silly because the determinant of the matrix representing the above system of equations is nonzero, hence we can always solve this from the information given anyway.

Comment: Ok... no proof needed. :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224769/244933

Comment: @theunamedguy Proof always better than no proof.

Comment: +1 for the math lesson.  -1 for making me relive math

Comment: @MatthewLundberg blasted, I was scooped.

Comment: I entered that answer mostly to demonstrate R's `solve` function.  And because it was fun.  It's still a duplicate...

Comment: @MatthewLundberg then close the question instead of telling me about it.

Comment: I lack the rep on MSE to close that question, and I lack the will to close this one.  Of course, the MSE question is already closed, and that was what I was referring to as a duplicate.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg right, this is cross MSO-MSE. Bah. I have no idea how we deal with that nowadays.

Comment: If you'd just stopped after the first paragraph, I wouldn't have a goddamned headache right now :-)